# Is this integral $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^{2/3}}dx$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_0^{\pi} x^{\frac{1}{3}}\cos(nx) dx\stackrel{IBP}{=} -\frac{1}{3n}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^{2/3}}dx$$

Is $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^{2/3}}dx$ bounded as $n \rightarrow \infty$  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left|\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin nx}{x^{2/3}}dx\right|\le\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{x^{2/3}}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^\pi\frac{dx}{x^{2/3}}=\left.\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}3x^{1/3}\right|_\epsilon^\pi=3\sqrt[3]\pi$$

so yes: it is bounded and the improper integral converges.